# findViewById of a Constraint Layout returns null

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with findViewById using Java in Android Studio. I'm triying to obtain a Constraint Layout to use .addview in it but it returns null.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gameLayout"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">
```

This is the line with problems:

```
ConstraintLayout mainLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);
```

And it returns null, what am I doing bad?

Thanks

Edit: Now I'm getting stucked afther this loops, what can be?

```
protected void generateGameZone(int m, int n){
        LinearLayout[] main_layouts = new LinearLayout[m];
        for(int i=0;i<main_layouts.length;i++){
            main_layouts[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
            main_layouts[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            main_layouts[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30,30));
            mainLayout.addView(main_layouts[i]);
        }
        LinearLayout[][] secondary_layouts = new LinearLayout[m][n];
        for(int i=0;i<secondary_layouts.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<secondary_layouts[i].length;j++){
                secondary_layouts[i][j] = new LinearLayout(this);
                secondary_layouts[i][j].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                secondary_layouts[i][j].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                TextView txtBox = new TextView(this);
                txtBox.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                txtBox.setId(i*10 + j);
                secondary_layouts[i][j].addView(txtBox);
                main_layouts[i].addView(secondary_layouts[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I obtain a black screen

Edit2: Black screen solved, now the layout I create with loops its not being showed

Comment: Have you already called `setContentView()`? Are you sure that this view is present in the xml file passed to `setContentView()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it seems like you are trying to add the `ConstraintLayout` programmatically to your activity. However `findViewById(int)` called from an `Activity` tries to find the **already existing** view in the hierarchy and returns `null` if it isn't found.

I think what you are looking for is either to inflate the layout using a [`LayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater) and then add it using `addView` as you suggested, or if this layout represents the root of your activity, use [`setContentView(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(int)) to let the activity handle the inflation.

Comment: `seems like you are trying to add the ConstraintLayout programmatically` what makes you say that ?

Comment: Sorry I just reread your question, and I think I have misunderstood. Can you provide the code for `onCreate` of your activity where I presume you're using `findViewById(int)`?

Comment: You understand well my question, I think this is the solution, because i'm doing the findViewById before the setContentView, let me try this. Thanks!

Comment: That'll be it, it will only work after `setContentView(int)`

Comment: Yes it was thanks! I've edited que main question, please if you can see it! Thanks

Comment: Maybe post the error or problem you're getting?

Comment: Yes sorry, i've edited it, i'm getting a black screen but both loops end and it returns